# Ajax Loader IE 7-Not showing

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am using ajax loader. The image that appears while loading is not being showed in IE7 but it is working fine in IE 8 and FF.
I have used following jquery for loader:-

```
initLoader(); 

function initLoader() 
{
    //Get the A tag
    var id = $('#dialogLoader');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
    $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2); 
}

function showLoader() 
{
    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').show();
    $('#dialogLoader').show(); 
}

function hideLoader() {
    $('#mask').hide();
    $('#dialogLoader').hide();
    $('.window').hide(); 
}

//To Start and hide loader 
$("#mask").bind("ajaxStart", function () {
  //alert('start');
  showLoader();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function () {
    //alert('end');
    hideLoader();
});
```

Here is the CSS:-

```
/* Loader CSS start */
#mask
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9000;
    opacity: 0.4;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)"; /* first!*/
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* second!*/
    background-color: gray;
    display: none;
}

#boxes .window
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 440px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 20px;
}

#boxes #dialogLoader
{
    width: 70px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: Arial;
}
/* Loader CSS End */
```

The mask is being displayed the window gets gray out but the loading image is not shown plz let me know how this can work for IE 7.
thanks!!!

Comment: I suspect that the problem is in the CSS. Can you post the css properties for #dialogLoader.

Comment: I'd start off by changing `id` to a different name, anything else even `_id`, I spent a few hours once and it turns out IE was returning a reference to a `window` property or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code you posted.

As your code was originally posted this line:

```
//To Start and hide loader $("#mask").bind("ajaxStart", function () {
```

was as I show above.

This was code that would not compile since it commented out the start of this statement.

Was this just a typo when you copied it here or is this the problem.

It might be there is an issue with `<CR>` and `<LF>`.

I would make sure they are correct and try.

Comment: I have added Css in the question Please look at it.

Comment: Sorry it may be commented while copying but it is not commented in the code.

Comment: Carriage return and line feed.

Answer (score 0):

My guesses: it does not like that you have a class name `.window`, referenced here:

```
$('.window').hide();
```

Or, and most probably, because of the variable named `id`, IE **hates** that because it references something else... I'm trying to find more info on this but it gave me similar trouble a while back.

**EDIT**: I may be completely off track with my above comments, it is just that after spending two days debugging an AJAX request because IE was the only browser that it did not play well with, I have become slightly paranoid when it comes upsetting IE.

Regarding the css you just posted, I would highly recommend using jQuery to set opacities, it is mostly cross-browser compatible, CSS just isn't.

Comment: Can you please elaborate I am unable to understand.

Comment: This may not be the issue but last time I had a problem in `IE` it was because I had a variable named `id`. `IE` was referencing it as something else and by the time it got to my server it was a really weird, long string. As soon I changed the name to something else this was fixed.

Comment: I have modified class window to loadwin and variable id to dial, Still I cant see any difference.